# Populating options in HTML with database value

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to populate the options in my html website with information from a database but it does not populate. 
All my other entries such as name, last name and address work but this is not working for me. It does not output the firstName values.

```
 <select name="text" id="firstName">

    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT firstName from Members";
    $results = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){ 
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rows['firstName'];?>"><?php echo $rows['firstName'];?></option>

    <?php
    } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: have you tried a var_dump($rows) ? Then you can see the content of your array

Comment: You can try to echo '<option value="<?php echo $rows['firstName'];?>"><?php echo $rows['firstName'];?></option>';

Comment: Attach your table structure